# Modal Window not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-11

I have a project in which I am using a Modal window, when the user clicks the snap button then the modal window appears and takes the snap. Same for the signature also.

But I am facing a problem. I saw that on my colleageues computer only IE11  it is not working. It is failing brutally.

Can anyone tell me a fix? I was browsing online for the error and found some jquery modal window options and i felt there are a lot of them. If jquery is the solution then please give some relevant links..

Thanks,
Abhijeet.

Comment: are you using any plugin? if so check the developer page regarding browser support.

Comment: It is a simple modal window... I am just using Jquery, but I am not using it for a modal window..!

Comment: no one can help you untill you show the code.